# How to import multiple objects, meshes, textures - and end up with one model and texture

Tags: texturing

Alright, please bear with me, I still consider myself a Blender newbie and am really hoping that I can provide enough detail to get my hopefully very simple question answered.

Here is my scenario, which has to do with UV textures.

I am learning Blender to assist with making video games.  I have several model pieces of a character that I did not make it myself.  It is composed of several meshes and texture files which make up its legs, feet, arms, chest, and there are even several meshes for the head and hair.  When I import all my files (they are FBX), I get my whole character model.

However, my game engine will only accept models that have one texture, regardless of whether the model is a stationary object or a playable character.

Now, I know how to combine objects with CTRL+J, and I've even observed that my several different meshes have three active UV maps (stack under UV Maps in the Object data tab) and if I make sure all of these maps across all the meshes have the same name when I combine the meshes, the textures will display on the viewport-rendered model appropriately.  Everything looks like how I want it to at this point, in the viewport.

My issue is that even after joining the meshes, I have several texture / material files.  I want to just have one so I can use the model with my game engine.

If I UV unwrap the model myself, the unwrapped UV looks nothing at all like the supplied texture file (unwrapped face meshes aren't laying over the face portion of the supplied image, things like that).  So I don't think Blender was how the model was created, but that's not important.

Searching for "How to merge textures" and "how to merge materials" do not give me results that help -- simply due to already having texture files.

I really need to be able to take these model files and end up with one FBX file, with one texture/material, and stay looking the way it looks in the viewport -- is this realistic at all?

Comment: You need to create a new UV map and then bake the existing multiple textures onto this map. Do a search for something like "baking multiple materials to a single UV map /texture". It will seem a little complicated at first until you understand what's going on so be patient. Here is one for Blender 2.79 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9airvjDaVh4

Comment: I tried to follow this tutorial and did not seem to have any issues even when baking.  But even when I follow the steps after the bake and remove my existing material slots and add a new one, the model is textured incorrectly.